# Visual studio does not open the graphical editor for Winforms anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am building really small 15 minute applications which help me and my Colleague with simple daily business work.

For that I am often using WinForm because its so damn fast for just making a window with 2 text boxes and a submit button.

Unfortunately recently I think I hit a button and the Graphical Editor wont open anymore. I will always be in the text editor view.

Online I cant find anything on how to open this bloody designer. I hope, someone of you knows the Answer.

**ISSUE:**
this opens:
[image]

**SHOULD BE:**
[image]

Comment: Did you try: Shift-F7 ? (From the _View_ menu)

Comment: You're using WinForms with net core 3, you must install an extension to use the designer, you can download it [there](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/Documentation/designer-releases/readme.md).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2019, you probably created the Windows Form using .Net Core 3.0:

[image]

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't yet have the designer for WinForms if you are targeting .NET Core. The .NET Framework version should work fine for your situation. If for some reason you need .NET Core for you application, you can use the preview version of the WinForms Designer for Visual Studio 2019, available here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/

**Update 12-10-2019:**
If you are running Visual Studio 2019 16.5 Preview 1, a VSIX is no longer needed to get the designer working for WinForms on .NET Core.

From the [.NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-to-net-core-windows-forms-designer-in-visual-studio-16-5-preview-1/):

> To use the designer:
>
> - You must be using Visual Studio 16.5 Preview 1 or a later version.
> - You need to enable the designer in Visual Studio. Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and select the Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps option.

Comment: uff, thank you so much. Could not find that anywhere in the web

Comment: Yeah, it's a little tricky if you aren't aware of it. Microsoft should give some kind of warning when selecting the correct project type if the designer is still in preview.

Comment: I am on version 16.5.4. No Forms Designer for .NET Core anywhere. Not even under Preview Features :(